# Alert User when someone replies to their post - SharePoint 2013 Community

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-alerts

I am looking for a solution to a very standard concept. In most social communities, there is a way for a user to be alerted if someone responds to something they posted. However, I am not seeing a way to accomplish this in the SharePoint 2013 Community Site. Need some assistance. Is there a way to accomplish this?

-Nick

Answer (score 1):

You can only alert on an item if it changes.  There is no OOB way to alert on a response to an item.

You can set up alerts on the list for new items but not for specific items (other than changes to that item).